# Is there a way to make Flask more verbose?

Tags: python, flask

I've been using Flask for a little while and find I prefer it to Rails in some ways, particularly for being lightweight. However, one area in which Rails is far superior in my opinion is error reporting. There are many times in Flask where I get an error in my browser, but my console shows no error at all (for example, trying to pull non-existant querystring parameters out of request.form produces a 400 Bad Request, but all you see on the console is the incoming request).

Is there any kind of a verbose mode on Flask which will give me detailed information on all of its behavior?

Answer (score 7):

The debug mode can be enabled via env variable (export FLASK_DEBUG=1) or within the code to allow printing traceback in case of errors as noted below:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to enable [debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode).

Comment: I've been doing that, but even running with debug=True produces a very anemic amount of information. For most things, the only thing Flask prints to the console are the HTTP requests.

Comment: When I use Flask in debug mode, exceptions in my code (like accessing a nonexistent dict key) trigger the debugger, which produces a complete backtrace with full source code and an interactive shell at each stack frame, all in the browser window. If that is anemic, I can't imagine what you might consider rich. Perhaps you ought to post some code so we can get a better idea of what you're seeing.

Comment: Maybe you need to tweak your config a bit for the exceptions to propagate?
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.trap_http_exception

Comment: Using debug mode (along with propagate_exceptions) did nothing for me. `Error 500` is still `Error 500`, with no extra information whatsoever. I don't know what you used to get a backtrace and an interactive shell but it's something more than just `debug=True`.

Answer (score 2):

Error handling is off by default in production mode at the moment and can be set up here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/

Comment: I think he wants to turn off the BadRequestKeyError behavior in development only.